# Option in Embedly card to exclude the TikTok part at the top and link at the bottom?

Tags: html, shopify, embedly

I am using the  component to embed a Tik Tok feed on my Shopify site.

Is there an option to exclude the TikTok part at the top and link at the bottom?

[image]

This is my code:

```
<amp-embedly-card
    data-url="{{block.settings.link}}"
    layout="responsive"
    width="100"
    height="400"
  >
 </amp-embedly-card>
```